# Typedef in c, how it works when it takes 2 arguments

Tags: c, function-pointers, declaration, typedef

Can anyone explain to me how this code snippet works?

```
typedef int (*compare)(const char*, const char*);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a declaration of an alias for the type pointer to function that has the return type `int` and two parameters of the type `const char *`.

```
typedef int (*compare)(const char*, const char*);
```

Using the alias you can declare a variable of the pointer type as shown in the demonstration program below

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*compare)(const char*, const char*);

int main( void )
{
    compare cmp = strcmp;
    printf( "\"Hello\" == \"Hello\" is %s\n",
            cmp( "Hello", "Hello" ) == 0 ? "true" : "false" );
}
```

where `strcmp` is a standard C string function declared like

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

and the pointer (variable) `cmp` is initialized by the address of the function.